# ELECTRON ERROR: shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

Im making an app with Electron, I have an input file tag in html

```
<input type="file" class="visually-hidden" id="upload-input" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" multiple>
```

Whenever I click it, window opens for images selection, but at the same time on its click I see this error on the terminal even I am not using any google drive etc.

```
2024-02-19T17:40:26.537ZE [19184:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_Abdul Rafey_shell
2024-02-19T17:40:26.543ZE [19184:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_Abdul Rafey_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-02-19T17:40:26.545ZE [15996:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_Abdul Rafey_shell
2024-02-19T17:40:26.545ZE [15996:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_Abdul Rafey_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140

2024-02-19T17:40:26.548ZE [3636:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:139:Connect Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_Abdul Rafey_shell
2024-02-19T17:40:26.548ZE [3636:ShellIpcClient] shell_ipc_client.cc:622:operator() Failed to connect to the server: NOT_FOUND: Can't connect to socket at: \\.\Pipe\GoogleDriveFSPipe_Abdul Rafey_shell [type.googleapis.com/drive.ds.Status='UNAVAILABLE_RESOURCE']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
apps/drive/fs/ipc/shell_ipc_client.cc:140
```

Everything in my app is working fine, but still i don't know why I'm getting this error.
I need help!!